# Mongodb Graph Lookup with fixed starting point

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB 3.4. Below is the structure of a collection

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron" }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew" }
```

I can use below query to find all the hierarchy

```
db.employees.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "employees",
         startWith: "$reportsTo",
         connectFromField: "reportsTo",
         connectToField: "name",
         as: "reportingHierarchy"
      }
   }
] )
```

But how to find the hierarchy only one employee e.g. Asya or Dan. What will be the query?

Comment: Add a match stage before graphlookup. `{$match:{name:"Asya"}}`

Comment: Thanks. I have also figured out after posting this question :)